# How to make Border controls to have the same width inside a single Grid control?

Tags: wpf, grid, width, border

I have something like this:

```
<MyView>  
    <Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="Module">
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
    </Style>    
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Border Name="Border1" Style="{StaticResource Module}">
        <!--some controls with non-fixed width-->
      </Border>
      <Border Grid.Row="1" Name="Border2" Style="{StaticResource Module}">
        <!--some controls with non-fixed width-->
      </Border>
      <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource Module}" Name="Border3">
        <!--some controls with non-fixed width-->
      </Border>
    </Grid>
</MyView>
```

The controls inside Border1 and Border2 might have different width, so their borders will also have different width, which doesn't look good. How do I force Border1 and Border2 border to have same width so it would look better?

The solution of setting same width manually doesn't count because the width of child controls of Border1 and Border2 may vary.

And the content of Border3 just eats up all available space, and this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />` to your Border Style

Comment: Grid didn't stretch Border1 to it's full width when I've set it's width to *. And "What you have now means that the first column will take up only as much space as it needs, and the 2nd column will take up all remaining space." is exactly what I want, so unfortunately your solution doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed your borders are in your Rows, not your Columns. Set your Border's `HorizontalAlginment="Stretch"` and it should work